# For Loop 60 items 10 per 10

Tags: python

I'm working with an api that gives me 61 items that I include in a discord embed in a for loop.

As all of this is planned to be included into a discord bot using pagination from DiscordUtils, I need to make it so it male an embed for each 10 entry to avoid a too long message / 2000 character message.

Currently what I use to do my loop is here: https://api.nepmia.fr/spc/ (I recomend the usage of a parsing extention for your browser or it will be a bit hard to read it)

But what I want to create is something that will look like that : https://api.nepmia.fr/spc/formated/

So I can iterate each range in a different embed and then use pagination.

I use [TinyDB](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to generate the JSON files I shown before with this script:

```
import urllib.request, json
from shutil import copyfile
from termcolor import colored
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query

db = TinyDB("/home/nepmia/Myazu/db/db.json")

def api_get():
    print(colored("[Myazu]","cyan"), colored("Fetching WynncraftAPI...", "white"))
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.wynncraft.com/public_api.php?action=guildStats&command=Spectral%20Cabbage") as u1:
            api_1 = json.loads(u1.read().decode())
            count = 0
            if members := api_1.get("members"):
                print(colored("[Myazu]","cyan"),
                      colored("Got expecteded answer, starting saving process.", "white"))
                for member in members:
                    nick = member.get("name")
                    ur2 = f"https://api.wynncraft.com/v2/player/{nick}/stats"
                    u2 = urllib.request.urlopen(ur2)
                    api_2 = json.loads(u2.read().decode())
                    data = api_2.get("data")
                    for item in data:
                            meta = item.get("meta")
                            playtime = meta.get("playtime")
                            print(colored("[Myazu]","cyan"),
                                  colored("Saving playtime for player", "white"),
                                  colored(f"{nick}...","green"))
                            db.insert({"username": nick, "playtime": playtime})
                            count += 1
            else: 
                print(colored("[Myazu]","cyan"), 
                      colored("Unexpected answer from WynncraftAPI [ERROR 1]", "white"))
    except:
        print(colored("[Myazu]","cyan"), 
              colored("Unhandled error in saving process [ERROR 2]", "white"))
    finally:
        print(colored("[Myazu]","cyan"),
              colored(f"Finished saving data for", "white"),
              colored(f"{count}", "green"), 
              colored("players.", "white"))
```

but this will only create a range like this : https://api.nepmia.fr/spc/

what I would like is something like this : https://api.nepmia.fr/spc/formated/

Thanks for your help!

PS: Sorry for your eyes I'm still new to Python so I know I don't do stuff really properly :s

Comment: Hello. For what it's worth I think the title of your question is a bit over specified since what it sounds like you're asking is how to paginate a sequence of elements, or break it into evenly sized chunks/bathed. The exact size of the list or the size of the batches are adjustable parameters in any solution to this general problem. Several possible answers are discussed here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Comment: Also in general your Python code looks mostly fine, especially for a beginner, so no need to apologize for it =)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

Reading what you said I think it is right to say what I'm trying to do is break my loop in chunks. 
Also sorry but the thread you send is neither not what I'm trying to achieve or it's me that is unable to understand it.

if you can maybe you could explain a simple way to achieve what I want so I can actually understand? Ofc I don't force you to.

Comment: Maybe what's not clear to me though is exactly in what context you want to output the paginated data. There's no reason to store it in paginated form in your database. Rather, when you query your database for generating output to the Discord bot you just need to paginate the results then. But I think some context might be missing for how you intend to use this.

Comment: Well, to be simple, I generate an embed field for each item in `_default`. Doing that make 61 field which is way too long for discord embeds, whithout talking of the fact that it is way more than 2000 characters. 

Making a range of 10 per 10 directly in the script I send would allow me to make an embed_creator def that would run for each of these range and generate my embeds correctly. And then I could make my pagination with DiscordUtils in 5 seconds.

Comment: What I'm saying is, this code just shows you reading from some API and storing some data in a TinyDB database. If I understand correctly you will later be querying that database to return elements from it. But you don't show that part. You want to just list the elements of the database on paginated form.

Comment: Yes, that's it. The other part is not the one that cause issues. If I can make the paginated form directly on the tinydb database the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up from the comments, you shouldn't store items in your database in a format that is specific to how you want to return results from the database to a different API, as it will make it more difficult to query in other contexts, among other reasons.

If you want to paginate items from a database it's better to do that when you query it.

According to the docs, you can iterate over all documents in a TinyDB database just by iterating directly over the DB like:

```py
for doc in db:
    ...
```

For any iterable you can use the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to associate an index to each item like:

```py
for idx, doc in enumerate(db):
    ...
```

If you want the indices to start with `1` as in your examples you would just use `idx + 1`.

Finally, to paginate the results, you need some function that can return items from an iterable in fixed-sized batches, such as one of the many solutions on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks) or elsewhere.  E.g. given a function `chunked(iter, size)` you could do:

```py
pages = enumerate(chunked(enumerate(db), 10))
```

Then `list(pages)` gives a list of lists of tuples like `[(page_num, [(player_num, player), ...]`.

The only difference between a list of lists and what you want is you seem to want a dictionary structure like

```
{'range1': {'1': {...}, '2': {...}, ...}, 'range2': {'11': {...}, ...}}
```

This is no different from a list of lists; the only difference is you're using dictionary keys to give numerical indices to each item in a collection, rather than the indices being implict in the list structure.  There's many ways you can go from a list of lists to this.  The easiest I think is using a (nested) dict comprehension:

```py
{f'range{page_num + 1}': {str(player_num + 1): player for player_num, player in page} 
 for page_num, page in pages}
```

This will give output in exactly the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Iguananaut for your precious help.

In the end I made something similar from your solution using a generator.

```
def chunker(seq, size):
    for i in range(0, len(seq), size):
        yield seq[i:i+size]

def embed_creator(embeds):
    pages = []
    current_page = None
    for i, chunk in enumerate(chunker(embeds, 10)):
        current_page = discord.Embed(
            title=f'**SPC** Last week online time',
            color=3903947)
        for elt in chunk:
            current_page.add_field(
                name=elt.get("username"), 
                value=elt.get("play_output"), 
                inline=False)
        current_page.set_footer(
            icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/513160124219523086/a_3dc65aae06b2cf7bddcb3c33d7a5ecef.gif?size=128", 
            text=f"{i + 1} / {ceil(len(embeds) / 10)}"
            )
        pages.append(current_page)
        current_page = None
    return pages
```

Using `embed_creator` I generate a list named pages that I can simply use with DiscordUtils paginator.